# How to calculate diff of sparse matrix in C++ using Eigen

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

I'm attempting to implement the below MATLAB code (from Eilers, 2003) in C++ using the Eigen library.

```
m = length(y);
E = speye(m);
D = diff(E, d);
C = chol(E + lambda * D' * D);
z = C\(C'\y);
```

I can create a sparse matrix easily enough:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> E(m,m);
E.setIdentity();
```

**But what's the equivalent of `diff` in Eigen for a sparse matrix?**

---

I could alternatively assume an order of differences value of 3, giving the coefficients of `-1, 3, -3, 1`. For an initial matrix of size 10 x 10, this would look like:

```
-1 3 -3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 -1 3 -3 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -1 3 -3 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 -1 3 -3 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 -1 3 -3 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 -1 3 -3 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 3 -3 1
```

**If I can't use `diff` then how can I efficiently generate the above sparse matrix?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB's `diff` simply finds the difference between adjacent elements in the matrix (defaulting to row-wise I think), so an easy way to achieve this is Eigen is through simple matrix subtraction, you just need to make sure you generate the right matrices.

You need a function that, given an `m x n` matrix `E`, will create two matrices `E1` and `E2`. `E1` is simply the first `m-1` rows of `E`, `E2` the last `m-1` rows (`E` without the first row). Subtracting `E1` from `E2` should then give you what you want.

Something like this:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> diff(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> E) {
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> E1 = E.block(0, 0, E.rows()-1, E.cols());
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> E2 = E.block(1, 0, E.rows()-1, E.cols());
    return E2 - E1;
}
```

Although I've not tested this, the idea should be correct. You can apply it recursively to get the `nth` difference approximation.

This operates row-wise, if you want the column wise `diff` it should be trivial to adapt this method.

Comment: This worked well, the only change needed other than making it recursive was to have it as `E2 - E1` to get the correct signs.